# Key binding for character insertion won't work in sublime text 3

Tags: sublime-text, key-binding

I am trying to make my sublime text 3 instert a "<" character if I press alt + z, and ">" if I insert alt + x since my keyboard has no <> keys. I managed to make this work properly in Sublime Text 2 a few months ago but I forgot how I did that.

After finding [this](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html) and [this](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/commands) document online I figured the right way to do it would be having this in `Default (windows.sublime-keymap)` in the user folder.

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+k", "alt+z"], "command": "insertCharacters", "args": "<" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+k", "alt+x"], "command": "insertCharacters", "args": ">" }
]
```

However, this seems to have done absolutely nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself. This is what I had to do:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+z"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": "<"} },
{ "keys": ["alt+x"], "command": "insert", "args": {"characters": ">"} }
```